# MySQL subquery not limited

Tags: mysql

I have a table that looks like this

```
-----------------------------------------
ID |    Food          | Maker           |
----------------------------------------
1  |   Burrito        | Chiptole        |
-------------------------------
2  |   Burrito        | FreeBirds       |
----------------------------------
3  |   Taco           | Chiptole        |
--------------------------------------
4  |   Taco           | Taco Bell       |
--------------------------------------
5  |   Taco           | Torchy's Taco's |
```

---

I want to retrieve all makers of the food that is specified in my IN clause  int his case ('burrito') but I also want to know who else makes this food.

My result *should* contain.

```
    Food    | Maker    | Maker List 
----------------------------------------------
1.  Burrito | Chiptole | Chiptole,Freebirds
--------------------------------------------
2.  Taco    | Chiptole | Chiptole,Taco Bell,Torchy's Taco's
```

the Maker must always remain the entry I specify. My query returns to me this list but it varies the Maker to the last row retrieved for that entry:

```
 SELECT ID,Food,Maker, GROUP_CONCAT(c.Maker) as Maker List
 FROM (Suppliers s) 
 WHERE Food
 IN (SELECT DISTINCT Food FROM Suppliers WHERE Maker IN ('Chiptole'))
```

**My result: This is wrong**

```
 Food       | Maker           | Maker List 
----------------------------------------------
1.  Burrito | FreeBirds       | Chiptole,Freebirds
--------------------------------------------
2.  Taco    | Torchy's Taco's | Chiptole,Taco Bell,Torchy's Taco's
```

Comment: What is the logic for `Maker` column? Lowest `ID`?

Comment: @PM77-1 From what I can see, it appears the OP wants the first row for the same `Food` column value.

Comment: @think123 - First as ordered by what?

Comment: sorry I made a typo the Maker should return to me what is specified in the IN part of my query in this case ALWAYS chipotle.

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
SELECT ID, Food, (
  SELECT s2.Maker FROM Suppliers s2
  WHERE s2.Food = s1.Food ORDER BY s2.ID ASC LIMIT 1
) AS Maker, GROUP_CONCAT(s1.Maker) AS Maker_List FROM Suppliers s1;
```

I'm not too sure about what exactly you are asking for, so feel free to provide suggestions and I will attempt to edit.

Comment: sorry I made a typo the Maker should be in Chiptole and the list should always have the Maker be Chiptole but the Maker List be a list of everyone who makes that food.

Comment: @Edward Then what about `SELECT "Chiptole" AS Maker"`?

Comment: Im not sure what you mean by `SELECT "Chiptole" AS Maker"` Chiptole is not a column header that exists in the table.

Comment: @Edward Writing `SELECT "Chiptole" AS Maker` will ensure that `Chiptole` is selected every time.

Answer (score 1):

You can try like below using `GROUP_CONCAT()`. [See a demo fiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d6386/3)

```
select ID, 
MIN(Maker) as Maker,
GROUP_CONCAT(Maker) as `Maker List`
FROM food_table
GROUP BY Food;
```

Results in:

[image]

Not sure if I have really understood you but I think you want to have `Maker` as a manual entry column. If yes then you can modify your query like

```
select ID, 
'FreeBirds' as Maker,
GROUP_CONCAT(Maker) as `Maker List`
FROM food_table
GROUP BY Food;
```

Comment: This isnt quite right I need to be able to specify the Maker because what if I want the same result for all foods made by Freebirds, maker should now return Freebirds..

Comment: See edit in answer if that helps. Else, I am bit confused as how you want to get your `maker` column.

Comment: This helps but I believe it sets the Maker = 'value' after it does all the joins, and retrieves all the data so i would be joining tables with the incorrect Maker value.

Comment: There is no `Joins` involved in my answer. It's a plain select statement with group by clause. modify your post and explain a bit more as to, what's the logic behind getting the maker.